# Uniform convergence on $\mathbb R$ of the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}} {\sqrt n + \cos x}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

> Is the following series of functions uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$?
>
> $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}} {\sqrt n + \cos x}$$

My attempt:  My answer is  No

I know that by Leibnitz  test  the  given series converges, but  by  using $M$- test

$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left|\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}} {\sqrt n + \cos x}\right| \le \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \left|\sum\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right| \neq 0$$

so  the  given series  is not uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$

Is  it correct ?

Comment: Why is the inequality after "My attempt" true? If it were true, how would it allow you to answer the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it converges uniformly on $\mathbb R$. You just apply [Dirichlet's test for uniform convergence](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_Test_for_Uniform_Convergence):

1. $\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n$ is uniformly bounded;
2. for each real $x$, $\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt n+\cos(x)}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is monotonic;
3. $\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt n+\cos(x)}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges uniformly to $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the usual bound on the remainder of an alternating series 
$$\left|\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}} {\sqrt k + \cos x}\right|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt n +\cos(x)}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt n-1}$$

Since the bound is independent of $x$ and goes to $0$, there is indeed uniform convergence.